# Why does the shape remains same when I sum a square numpy array along either directions?

Tags: python, numpy

I was expecting the shape to be (1,3) when I sum along axis=0 i.e. rows. But the shape remains same in both cases. Why is that?

```
>>> arr = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
>>> arr
array([[0, 1, 2],
   [3, 4, 5],
   [6, 7, 8]])
>>> arr.sum(1)
array([ 3, 12, 21])
>>> arr.sum(1).shape
(3,)
>>> arr.sum(0)
array([ 9, 12, 15])
>>> arr.sum(0).shape
(3,)
```

Comment: Shape changes, just the representation of a tuple with one element is like that. More info - https://wiki.python.org/moin/TupleSyntax, https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`numpy.sum` returns:

> An array with the same shape as `a`, with the **specified axis removed**.

With one axis removed in both cases, you are left with a singleton tuple.

*2 axes - 1 specified axis =  1 axis*

However, passing `keepdims` as `True` in both gives different shapes, retaining all the axes in the original array with a corresponding change of length along the specified axis:

```
>>> arr.sum(axis=0, keepdims=True)
array([[ 9, 12, 15]])
>>> arr.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)
array([[ 3],
       [12],
       [21]])
```

Comment: Thanks @Moses. Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Because summing along the axis of a ND array yields a (N-1)D array. This makes sense if you consider that

```
np.sum([1,2,3]) == 6  # a 0D 'array'
```

If you want to turn your `arr.sum(1)` into a `(1, 3)` or `(3, 1)` 2D array, then use

```
s = arr.sum(0)[np.newaxis, :]  # (1, 3)
```

or

```
s = arr.sum(1)[:, np.newaxis]  # (3, 1)
```

Comment: Passing `keepdims=True` might be more explicit.

Comment: Yes, I completely forgot about that param. +1

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) this is what you'll get:

> Returns:
>
> sum_along_axis : ndarray
>
> An array with the same shape as a, with the specified axis removed. If a is a 0-d array, or if axis is None, a scalar is returned. If an output array is specified, a reference to out is returned.

The shape of `arr` is indeed `(3,3)` and is two-dimensional. If you remove one axis you'll be left with a shape of `(3,)` - which is one-dimensional.

An array with shape `(1,3)` still has two axes.

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.arrays` have a logic which is not the same than  Matlab or even mathematics. From [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html) :

> Handling of vectors (one-dimensional arrays) For array, the vector
>   shapes 1xN, Nx1, and N are all different things. Operations like
>   A[:,1] return a one-dimensional array of shape N, not a
>   two-dimensional array of shape Nx1. Transpose on a one-dimensional
>   array does nothing.

Numpy story began not with linear algebra,  so a one dimension object is always *horizontal*, cannot be transposed, an so on. It is confusing first time with a different background, but with a lot advantages in other fields. in numpy
 2-dim arrays are lines (dim0) of columns(dim1), like for matrix, but selecting a line or a column return always ... a line !

As an example :

```
In [1]: m=np.arange(6).reshape(3,2)

In [2]: m
Out[2]: 
  array([[0, 1],
         [2, 3],
         [4, 5]])

In [3]: m[0,:]  
Out[3]: array([0, 1])

In [4]: m[:,0]
Out[4]: array([0, 2, 4])
```

This convention accepted, nothing is very difficult.

Comment: Linear algebra does distinguish between column and row vectors, but is that universal in mathematics?  Aren't there mathematical formulations that, like `numpy`, allow arrays to be `n` dimensions, for n>=0.  Note that the original MATLAB just had 2d matrices, because it was a front end to FORTRAN linear algrebra code.  Higher dimensions, cells, structs are all additions.

Comment: I am not mathematician, but was troubled first times by this feature. It's the reason of this post, Hope it will help some ones.