# Why does summing a sparse matrix leave an empty dimension?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

When summing a `numpy.ndarray`, it reduces the dimensionality of the array, unless we set `keepdims=True`. However, this doesn't seem to be true for Scipy's sparse matrices:

```
import scipy.sparse

matrix = scipy.sparse.coo_matrix([[0, 1], [2, 1]])
print(matrix.shape)                 # (2, 2) as expected.
print(matrix.sum().shape)           # () as expected.
print(matrix.sum(axis=0).shape)     # (1, 2) but expected (2,).
print(matrix.sum(axis=0)[0].shape)  # (1, 2) but expected (2,).
```

As shown from the last line in the example, I cannot even select the resulting vector. Further, trying to cast the result of the sum to a dense Numpy array fails:

```
matrix.toarray()              # This works.
matrix.sum(axis=0).toarray()  # AttributeError: 'matrix' has no 'toarray'.
```

How can I compute the sum of a sparse matrix along one dimension and obtain the result as a dense array?

Comment: I think this is because it's a "matrix" and not an array. therefore you have to have two dimensions.

Comment: @PaulH Why can I cast the original matrix to a Numpy array, but not the object returned from the sum?

Comment: sparse matrix vs numpy.matrix?

Comment: You are right, the sum returns a Numpy matrix, so `np.asarray(matrix.sum(axis=0))[0]` works. Should this be considered a bug in Scipy? If it returns a Numpy object anyway, the `numpy.ndarray` type that supports the correct rank would be better suited.

Comment: It's consistent with `np.matrix`, [which also produces a matrix from `sum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.sum.html#numpy.matrix.sum).

Comment: @user2357112 Interesting. Two bug reports then? ;-)

Comment: @danijar nah, `np.matrix` is pretty much deprecated, but unfortunately, `scipy.sparse_matrix` acts like a `np.matrix`. A sparse-ndarray would be great.

Comment: No need for bug reports.  This is a well established, and generally, accepted behavior.

Comment: The 2d nature of sparse matrices is built in to the code at many levels.  Most of the theory comes from linear algebra and tasks like finite element and difference linear equation solution.  The `csr` format uses `indptr` and `indices` attributes.  It doesn't use `strides` (at least not directly).  As far as I know, MATLAB hasn't extended their sparse code to allow higher dimensions.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga We are working on it `;-)` https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/8162

Answer (score 4):

A sparse matrix, while a distinct class (classes depending on format), tries to behave like `np.matrix` (which in turn behaves like an old fashioned MATLAB matrix).  Its shape is always 2d, and indexing, summing, and related actions, returns 2d.

```
In [172]: M = sparse.csr_matrix([[0,1],[2,1]])
In [173]: M
Out[173]: 
<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Total sum produces a scalar, or 0d array:

```
In [174]: M.sum()
Out[174]: 4
In [175]: _.shape
Out[175]: ()
In [176]: type(__)
Out[176]: numpy.int32
```

Axis sum produces a 2d column or row vector dense matrix:

```
In [177]: M.sum(axis=0)
Out[177]: matrix([[2, 2]], dtype=int32)
In [178]: _.shape
Out[178]: (1, 2)
In [179]: M.sum(axis=1)
Out[179]: 
matrix([[1],
        [3]])
In [180]: _.shape
Out[180]: (2, 1)
```

This is the same behavior you get from a dense matrix, e.g. `M.todense()`.  `keepdims=True` provides something like this for arrays (people coming from MATLAB complain about the `sum` reducing the dimensions).

A dense matrix has a handy `.A1` property that converts it to a 1d array:

```
In [181]: M.sum(axis=1).A1
Out[181]: array([1, 3])
In [182]: M.sum(axis=0).A1
Out[182]: array([2, 2], dtype=int32)
```

`.A` works for both sparse matrix and dense matrix, but only sparse has a `toarray` method (and `todense`).  Like I said, sparse imitates the dense matrix, but isn't a subclass.

Sparse axis sum actually does a matrix multiplication; dense matrix * sparse matrix produces a dense matrix:

```
In [186]: M*np.matrix([[1],[1]])
Out[186]: 
matrix([[1],
        [3]], dtype=int32)
In [187]: np.matrix([[1,1]])*M
Out[187]: matrix([[2, 2]], dtype=int32)
```

A complaint about array sum not leaving this 'empty' (singular is a term, 1 not 0) dimension:

[Why does the shape remains same when I sum a square numpy array along either directions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47591481/why-does-the-shape-remains-same-when-i-sum-a-square-numpy-array-along-either-dir)